# Multiprocessing Pool is running the whole code for every process created instead of just the function passed to it

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

The python code does a data pull and pre-processing (to convert the data into an iterable for Pool Map to run) and then calls Pool Map to automatically subset the data and run in parallel. However, I find that the data pull and preprocessing are running in each process again in addition to the function that should be running in each process.

Code is as follows:

```
#Data Pull
orig_data= pd.read_csv(<fileath>)

#Data Preprocessing
start=time.time()
transformed_input=list() # transformed_input is populated with data from orig_data dataframe as required
end=time.time()
print("Preprocessing Time")
print(end-start)


def examplefunction(transformed_input_sub):
    # Required Function
    return output

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from multiprocessing import Pool
    p=Pool()
    s=time.time()
    output=p.map(examplefunction,transformed_input)
    p.close()
    p.join()
    e=time.time()
    print("Time Taken")  
    print(e-s)
```

> **Expected Output:**
>   Preprocessing Time
>   5.01
>   Time Taken
>   10
>
> **Actual Output when running on 4 processes:**
>   Preprocessing Time
>   5.01
>   Preprocessing Time
>   5.12
>   Preprocessing Time
>   5.35
>   Preprocessing Time
>   5.41
>   Time Taken
>   10

However, the **output of this code is correct** (and verified) despite the preprocessing running for each process, which is shouldn't be doing as far as I am aware. The problem then arises when instead of a pulling data from a csv containing only a small portion of the data, I use a Teradata Pull for close to 50 million records. The TD pull without multiprocessing works perfectly fine, but with multiprocessing throws the following error:

> No more spool space in *database name*

This is probably each process is running the TD Pull.
How can I ensure the Pool runs only the function passed to it in parallel and not the complete code from scratch?

I have tried changing the order of code blocks, calling import statements outside the name == 'main' block, and also put the data pull and preprocessing code in a separate python code and called it using exec() within the main program.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does pool run the entire file multiple times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31858352/why-does-pool-run-the-entire-file-multiple-times)

Comment: @CaptainTrunky, the problem with that approach is that transformed_input will then no longer be accessible by the processes created and throw "transformed_input" does not exist.

Comment: That's correct. You could use [managers](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#managers) for passing variables between workers instead of using global variables.

Comment: Have you considered multiple threads instead of processes ?

Comment: @peebs96: The separate processes have separate copies of `transformed_input` anyway.

Comment: @CaptainTrunky Can I use a manger to pass just the transformed_input from parent process to all the child processes? Any example links you may have come across that explains this  would be super helpful since I'm new to multiprocessing and it's literature. Thanks though, I understand what the problem is now!

Comment: @ma3oun I am running the code on a system with 48 processors, I don't think threading will solve this efficiently since there isn't much CPU Idle time and I want to leverage the multiple processors instead.

Comment: @peebs96 I think [this one](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process#sharing-state-between-processes) is pretty helpful.

Comment: @peebs96 And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33012638/python-multiprocessing-concurrency-using-manager-pool-and-a-shared-list-not-wor) one